# finding position of characters in db2 column

Tags: sql, db2

I have a db2 column with string values as:

```
"abc, xyzq, pqr abc, abc xyz pqr, 13f"
```

The position of the comma are (starting at position 1): 4,10,19,32

How to get all indexes of commas in a query?

I am using DB2 9.5

Comment: ... How do you want the results returned - as a set (ie, each new position in the row should be a new row in the results), or a delimited list of some sort (difficult to deal with later in SQL).  DB2 has the [`POSSTR`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000835.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-112) function which finds the **first** instance of a given string.  Why is the data stored like this?  And why do you care about the _position_ (as opposed to the data itself)?  What do you want this information for?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I want all the comma separated tokens divided into different columns. So the example string should result in 5 columns.

Comment: Unless you know ahead of time how many there are (or only care about a certain number), you need dynamic SQL.  Even then, you need some way to find the "next" entry - either by recursively applying `POSSTR`, or writing your function (DB2 accepts multiple languages).  I'm still not convinced that the position is what your really need.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I am trying: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4533   However, I am getting error DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: );er where end > start;)

Comment: Turns out there were a couple of syntax errors in that answer, I've since corrected them.  Generally such things are off-topic for questions though: you're getting an explicit message that "you're doing this part wrong", so you're expected to fix it.  Especially because the message you just quoted doesn't include _what it's complaining about_ (probably, because `END` is a reserved keyword).  There's possibly other questions on this site that deal with splits, too...